# Swift - the completion ends before the animation does

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have the problem that the completion of the animation function ends before the animation itself does.

The array `progressBar[]` includes multiple `UIProgressViews`. When one is finished animating I want the next one to start animating and so on. But right now they all start at once.
How can I fix this?

```
@objc func updateProgress() {

        if self.index < self.images.count {
            progressBar[index].setProgress(0.01, animated: false)
            group.enter()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                    self.progressBar[self.index].setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
                }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                    if finished == true {
                        self.group.leave()
                    }
                })
            }
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.index += 1
                self.updateProgress()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think, group.notify(queue: .main) {
                self.index += 1
                self.updateProgress()
            } this call should be inside your completion handler isn't it?

Comment: No. That is not the problem. group.notify(queue: .main) { self.index += 1 self.updateProgress() } gets called and works just fine, but my problem is that it is already called before the animation of the UIProgressView has ended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `UIView.animate()` can only be used on animatable properties, and `progress` is not an animatable property. "Animatable" here means "externally animatable by Core Animation." `UIProgressView` does its own internal animations, and that conflicts with external animations. This is `UIProgressView` being a bit over-smart, but we can work around it.

`UIProgressView` does use Core Animation, and so will fire `CATransaction` completion blocks. It does not, however, honor the duration of the current `CATransaction`, which I find confusing since it does honor the duration of the current UIView animation. I'm not actually certain how both of these are true (I would think that the UIView animation duration would be implemented on the transaction), but it seems to be the case.

Given that, the way to do what you're trying looks like this:

```
func updateProgress() {
    if self.index < self.images.count {
        progressBar[index].setProgress(0.01, animated: false)

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            self.index += 1
            self.updateProgress()
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear,
                       animations: {
                        self.progressBar[self.index].setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
        })
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

I'm creating a nested transaction here (with begin/commit) just in case there is some other completion block created during this transaction. That's pretty unlikely, and the code "works" without calling begin/commit, but this way is a little safer than messing with the default transaction.

Comment: Everything works now, but the first UIProgressView. It isn't show at all first and then the animation is way faster then the others. Do you have a solution? But besides that it works just fine. :D

Comment: Are you calling `updateProgress` prior to `viewDidAppear`? For example, do you call it in `viewDidLoad`? That'll cause glitches on the first animation because it hasn't been laid out yet. (I'm guessing this is some version of your problem, because I made this mistake myself and had weird glitches on the first animation…)

Comment: I'm not doing it in an UIViewController. I'm doing it in an UICollectionViewCell class. So I'm calling it from awakeFromNib(). So how am I supposed to call it?

Comment: yeah; `awakeFromNib` is probably still too early. Put the call in a `DispatchQueue.main.async()` call. That should push it onto the next event loop, which will be after everything has laid out.